# how to format json with array of json

Tags: php, json

I want output in json like this

```
response:{url="www.google.com/raj.png", size=12.344KB},{url="www.google.com/raj2.png", size=12.344KB},{url="www.google.com/raj4.png", size=12.344KB}
```

But currently i am getting

```
"url=> www.google.com/img1.png size => 12.344 KB,url=> www.google.com/img2.png size => 12.344 KB"
```

Comment: Format your array in that case. Post your code where you encoding your json so that we may help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Using some loop here
{
  $response[] = array('url' => 'url_value','size' => 'file_size');
}

//without loop hardcoded values:

$response = array ( array('url' => "www.google.com/raj.png",'size' => "12.344KB"),
array('url' => "www.google.com/img2.png",'size' => "10.344KB") );

return json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$out= Array(
 Array('url'=>'www.goog', 'size'=>'12KB'),
 Array('url'=>'moogle', 'size'=>'13KB')
);
echo Json_encode($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are formatting your array, but if you define it like this it should do the trick:

```
$response_array = array(
  'response' => array(
    array(
      'url'  => 'www.google.com/raj.png',
      'size' => '12.344KB',
    ),
    array(
      'url'  => 'www.google.com/raj.png',
      'size' => '12.344KB',
    ),
    array(
      'url'  => 'www.google.com/raj.png',
      'size' => '12.344KB',
    ),
  ),
);

$respose_json = json_encode($response_array);
echo($response_json);
```

---

For looping through some results, try something like this:

```
$response_array = array('response' => array());
foreach($result_set as $result_item) {
  $response_item = array();
  $response_item['url'] = $result_item['url'];
  $response_item['size'] = $result_item['size'];
  $response_array['response'][] = $response_item;
}

$respose_json = json_encode($response_array);
echo($response_json);
```

With the `$result_set` above being whatever data you've pulled from a DB, server, etc.